# Blender won't render image properly

Tags: rendering

Anyways, I have been rendering this office for a while now, and everything was fine. I came back after modelling something else and everytime I render an image this screen appears. [image] How can I fix this black screen?

Comment: There are lots of questions with exactly the same problem and very similiar wording. Please use the search thoroughly next time.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I fixed it. I had an image strip in the video editor but I deleted the images and so it didnt render anything. I deleted the strip and it renders like it used to.